# context envcontext jdbc

Tags: java-ee, jdbc

```
Context initContext = new InitialContext();
    Context envContext = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
    DataSource ds = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("\"jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres");what is that and  how i can fill that!PLease help.
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.